# What does type %%a ^& break ^> %%a mean in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

What does `type %%a ^& break ^> %%a` mean in the code block below of a batch file?

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type %%a ^& break ^> %%a ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    echo %%i
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%%a" echo(!line:%WIN32%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: That depends entirely on what `%%a` is. That part is outside of the snippet you posted, so I can't really say. That said, `break` doesn't really do anything anymore, so I suspect this is simply poorly-written code.

Comment: It types a file and immediately deletes its contents, so `for` is able "to process the file's previous content despite it's now empty" and can write the altered content to the now empty file. Not an unusual trick to "edit" a file, but dangerous, because you lose your data if the loop fails for any reason. It would be safer to write to a temporary file and replace the original file with the temporary one after the loop.

Comment: `break` is a depreciated command (kept for compatibility reasons, but not doing anything anymore). It has no output, so you can redirect that "no output" to a file, effectively destroying its content and making it a zero-byte, empty file.

Comment: Let me recommend not to use this technique, because it actually opens and closes the file for every single line, which is not quite efficient. Best is to redirect the whole `for /F` loop to a temporary file and to replace the original file then: `> "%%a.tmp" (for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%%a") do ( … ))`, then `move /Y "%%a.tmp" "%%a" >nul`